# Why Windows 10 locks processor's base frequency to 2.39Ghz when i have 3Ghz cpu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cpu, performance

I have intel core2 duo E6850 with 3Ghz base frequency but after installing Windows 10 (had windows 7) the processor never goes upto that mark, even I am running heavy apps like Andoid Studio the max frequency is is about 2.4Ghz. The task manager shows the same as base frequency while the processor's actual base frequency is 3Ghz. Here is the screenshot of Task manager:

[image: task manager snap]

I checked the frequency using HWiNFO while running stress test (in case task manager showing wrong info) and here is the snap:[image: HWiNFO snap]

Also here is what system properties is showing:

[image: System properties snap]

I googled about it and have already tried following:

1. setting power option to high performance
2. changing max and min performance values of power plan
3. modifying start value of intelppm in registry to 4
4. running cmd command "ren intelppm.sys intelppm.sys.bak"
5. using **throttlestop** and unchecking "BD PROCHOT"

What works is that when I boot from linux live usb (Zorin OS) I was able to perform tasks and use upto that 3ghz frequency speed. I don't understand why Windows 10 cannot do that? Should install windows 7 again or perhaps linux?

Comment: Please post screenshots from [CPU-z's](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) processor & motherboard information pages, or [HWInfo64](https://www.hwinfo.com/download/).

Comment: Hi @paddywan, cpu-z show the same info as the task manager, my motherboard is zebronics 945

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-power-throttling-windows-10

Comment: Thanks @Moab, I tried but the issue still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HWiNFO shows EIST in red. Is SpeedStep enabled in the BIOS? Disabling SpeedStep causes more problems than it solves.
If HWiNFO is correct, your motherboard does not correctly support your CPU. The later Core 2 Duo CPUs used a faster bus speed. The default bus speed for your E6850 is 333.3 MHz. The early Core 2 Duo used a 266.6 MHz bus speed. Make sure you are using the latest BIOS version for your motherboard and that it supports your CPU. This is why your CPU is not running at full speed. 9.0 X 333.3 = 3000 MHz and 9.0 X 266.6 MHz = 2400 MHz